# R Programming - pmax with data frame

Tags: r

I was trying to use pmax function in my program. I had a data frame of numbers and I was trying to compare it with a single number. Output had NA's.

I figured out that data frame does not work with pmax so I changed data frame to matrix. And it worked. I was curious as to why data frame was returning NA. Is it something to do with recycling?

code:-

```
mat <- matrix(runif(500), nrow = 20, ncol = 5)
df <- as.data.frame(mat)


pmax(mat, .5) # No NA's

pmax(df, .5) # Many NA's
```

Comment: I think it is better to know the difference of how `pmax` works in `data.frame` and `matrix`  What u need is `pmax(unlist(df), .5)`  A `matrix` is a `vector` with dimensions.  So, each value is available to compare with `.5`, while `data.frame` is a `list` of columns.  U need to unlist it.  `all.equal(c(pmax(mat, .5)), pmax(unlist(df), .5), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE`

Comment: @akrun thanks for answering the question. I am new to R and still wrapping my head around list. I understand that data frame is type of list and unlisting it works. When I was checking the output of data frame, I had NA's only places where values in data frame were less than 0.5. Pmax returned correct values when values in dataframe were greater than 0.5. Is there a specific reason for it?

Comment: It is not the case.  If you are creating dataset with a set seed i.e. `set.seed(24);
 mat <- matrix(runif(500), nrow = 20, ncol = 5);df <- as.data.frame(mat)`  you will notice that `pmax(df, 0.5)` that the first 2 values are less than 0.5 and gets replaced by 0.5 in the 'V1' column.  It depends on the function `pmax` where it depends on the number of columns in the dataset. i.e. `mmm[change] <- each[change]`

Comment: It means that for the first 5 elements, there is no problem and it behaves correctly.  As soon as it goes to the next element of V1 i.e. greater than the number of columns, wherever it is lower than the 0.5 gets the NA

Comment: @akrun I am getting a sense of it and thanks for answering. But probably I should read more about list and data frame. I am still not able to understand why after 5 elements it starts giving NA's.

Comment: I posted my comments as a solution along with some detailed analysis on why it is occuring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of the problems where the replication of the value on the second argument is not recycled fully, i.e. it depends on the number of columns.  This could be the reason

```
rep(0.5, ncol(df))[df < 0.5]
#[1] 0.5 0.5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#[41]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Note that for the first 2 values, the 0.5 is correctly being changed as the logical matrix is TRUE for those elements `df < 0.5` while it is not the case because 0.5 is replicated only based on the number of columns.

Suppose, we look at `pmax`, the line

```
mmm[change] <- each[change]
```

is problematic.  We can check the output by `print`ing the output of 'each' and 'each[change].  If we modify the function to include the `print` statement

```
pmax2 <- function (..., na.rm = FALSE) 
{
    elts <- list(...)
    if (length(elts) == 0L) 
        stop("no arguments")
    if (all(vapply(elts, function(x) is.atomic(x) && !is.object(x), 
        NA))) {
        mmm <- .Internal(pmax(na.rm, ...))
        mostattributes(mmm) <- attributes(elts[[1L]])
    }
    else {
        mmm <- elts[[1L]]
        has.na <- FALSE
        as <- methods::as
        asL <- function(x) if (isS4(x)) 
            as(x, "logical")
        else x
        for (each in elts[-1L]) {
            l1 <- length(each)
            l2 <- length(mmm)
            if (l2 && (l2 < l1 || !l1)) {
                if (l1%%l2) 
                  warning("an argument will be fractionally recycled")
                mmm <- rep(mmm, length.out = l1)
            }
            else if (l1 && (l1 < l2 || !l2)) {
                if (l2%%l1) 
                  warning("an argument will be fractionally recycled")
                each <- rep(each, length.out = l2)
            }
            na.m <- is.na(mmm)
            na.e <- is.na(each)
            if (has.na || (has.na <- any(na.m) || any(na.e))) {
                if (any(na.m <- asL(na.m))) 
                  mmm[na.m] <- each[na.m]
                if (any(na.e <- asL(na.e))) 
                  each[na.e] <- mmm[na.e]
            }
            nS4 <- !isS4(mmm)
            if (isS4(change <- mmm < each) && (nS4 || !isS4(each))) 
                change <- as(change, "logical")
            change <- change & !is.na(change)
            print(change)
            mmm[change] <- each[change]
            print(each)
            print(each[change])
            if (has.na && !na.rm) 
                mmm[na.m | na.e] <- NA
            if (nS4) 
                mostattributes(mmm) <- attributes(elts[[1L]])
        }
    }
    mmm
}
```

Now, we check the `print` output based on applying `pmax2` on 'df'

```
invisible(pmax2(df, 0.5))
#       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [7,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [9,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[11,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[12,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[13,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[14,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[15,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[16,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[17,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[18,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[19,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[20,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
# [1] 0.5 0.5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#[41]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Note that this is exactly the same output we got with the `rep` mentioned earlier.

However, on a `matrix` this is not executed because of the `if/else` statements

```
invisible(pmax2(mat, 0.5))
```

nothing is printed

---

It is better to apply `pmax` on a `matrix` when compared with a single element than on a `data.frame` and that element.  Otherwise, we can `unlist` the `data.frame` or convert it to `matrix`

```
all.equal(c(pmax(mat, .5)), pmax(unlist(df), .5), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
mat <- matrix(runif(500), nrow = 20, ncol = 5)
df <- as.data.frame(mat)
```

Comment: I went through the whole code as you pointed out and understood why we can not use data frame.  This has been a great learning question for  me. Thanks @akrun for answering it in such a detailed fashion :)